# Email Activation for Registered Users

Tags: php, email

I have a website that I am creating using php and is hosted with dreamhost and I want my registered users to receive an activation email that will have the following address to click on or put in the url:

```
http://[website]/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" . $register_data['email_code'] . "
```

When the site is live, I register a user and it is successful, but I receive no email. But when I put in the link as above with the correct email and email_code for the newly registered user my activation is successful. So my question is how can I set up the email function to send the activation email when the website is live and not running on localhost?

Comment: You have to make sure php mail is setup on your web server, otherwise, it can't send email without an installed API or smtp setup.

Comment: @danL now how can I do that?

Comment: It depends on what kind of server it is. I would guess it's a Linux (Red Hat) sever? Either way, I would need to know what kind of server OS is installed on it to setup the sendmail path, assuming it's not just currently prohibited in the configuration. If it is simply disabled in the configuration, you would just need to edit your php.ini file on your server to allow it. However, if you have to actually setup the sendmail path, you probably would need a significant amount of help in doing so.

Comment: @danL i am using a Mac OS. I also have downloaded mamp and xampp if that helps.

Comment: @danL But for my database I am using xampp

Comment: I thought you said it was working on your localhost server but not on your web server? I'm confused, sorry. Are you hosting a website off of your Mac?

Comment: @danL No its not working on my localhost nor my webserver. The logic I have coded works but I just can't send the email to my users when its on my webserver. How can I do that?

Comment: As I said, you'll need to contact your webhost and find out if they even have SMTP setup yet. If they do not, I think you're pretty much out of luck. If they do, you can ask them if you can have access to your php.ini file so you can setup mail.